# webshims validate 000-00-00 date on submit

Tags: javascript, validation, date, webshim

I would like  to validate an input date with a null value like this

```
<input type="date" value="0000-00-00" id="date" />
```

On submit I have a this logical message 'Please enter a date.'

I found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/zRGd9/embedded/result,html,js,css/.
If you know how to do this, here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/zRGd9/24/

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not a date and depending of the browser implementation this value is either emptied or considered a badInput or a typeMismatch.

If you want to use this you have the following options:

1. Strictly empty it yourself:

`$('input[type="date"]')
        .on('change.empty', function () {
            var val = $.prop(this, 'value');
            if (!val || val == '0000-00-00') {
                $.prop(this, 'value', '');
            }
        })
        .trigger('change.empty')
    ;`

1. Set a novalidate attribute:

```

```
<form novalidate="">
       <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

1. Use a different input if you also want to allow non valid date:

```

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="31" /> 
<input type="number" min="0" max="12" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="9999" />
```

Comment: I will try the first trick but are you sure for the tigger() rrrr ;¬)

Comment: Yes, the trigger is for the fact, that your server might initially render this value. The fact, that I'm triggering the change event with a namespace ('.empty') makes it bulletproof, only this listener and not other listeneres are called.

Comment: I have just added some small changes here. This might look stupid at first, but in case of a badInput error, the value in DOM world is '', but the value in the user world is there.

Comment: It's just because you write tigger not tRigger ;¬)